# ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice, listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Tags: python, pandas, types, statistics, covariance

I want to calculate covariance from scratch. The **covariance** raised

> ValueError( ValueError: Location based indexing can only have
> [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is
> EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types error.

What should I change to make the code work?

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')
df = df.sample(frac=1)

# Create a list for each column of the dataframe
for col in df:
    col_list = df[col].tolist()

    # Mean
    sums = 0
    for a in range(len(col_list)):
        sums += df.iloc[a]
    mean = sums / len(col_list)
    mean = [m for m in pd.to_numeric(mean, errors='coerce')]

    # Standard deviation
    for mean in range(len(col_list)):
        sd = math.sqrt(mean)

    # Correlation matrix
    cov = []
    for j in range(mean):
        for k in range(mean):

            # Random variables
            var = ((df.iloc[i, j] - str(range(mean))) * (df.iloc[i, k] - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))

            # Covariance
            covariance = sum(var) / (mean - 1)
            print(covariance)
```

Traceback

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\Fibonacci recursive.py",
> line 31, in <module>
>     covariance = sum(var) / (mean - 1)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\Fibonacci recursive.py",
> line 28, in <genexpr>
>     var = ((df.iloc[i, j] - str(range(mean))) * (df.iloc[i, k] - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
> line 889, in __getitem__
>     return self._getitem_tuple(key)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
> line 1450, in _getitem_tuple
>     self._has_valid_tuple(tup)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
> line 725, in _has_valid_tuple
>     raise ValueError( ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is
> EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems as `df.iloc[i, j]` (similar to [k,i]) is the issue. See [iloc reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for options.

Depending on your `DataFrame` I think you want to access the value at position [i,j] and [i,k], correct?
So you get row `i` with `.iloc[i]` and then access the column you need. A simple example below to retrieve one value with which you perform you calculation.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b' : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
})


i = 2
j = 1

value = int(df.iloc[i:i+1,j]) # output: 8
```

Comment: That gives me `TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [r] of type str`

Comment: `var = ((df.iloc[i].j - str(range(mean))) * (df.iloc[i].k - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))` gave me `TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key` error

Comment: `var = ((df.iloc[i:, j] - str(range(mean))) * (df.iloc[i:, k] - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))` raises `TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [r] of type str`. Not sure what `nr_values` mean.

Comment: ```nr_values``` would be the index to which you want to slice. If you want to have only one value, just use index i+1. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tried `var = ((df.iloc[i:i+1, j] - str(range(mean))) * (df.iloc[i:i+1, k] - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))` and `var = ((str(df.iloc[i:i+1, j]) - str(range(mean))) * (str(df.iloc[i:i+1, k]) - str(range(mean))) for i in str(range(mean)))`. Both gave me `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` error.

Comment: I suppose this is caused by ```str(range(mean)))``` which should returns type `str` which you want to substract. Use `print(type(str(range(mean))))` to verify. You probably want to be more precise with your variables because you assign `mean`multiple times changing its type.

Comment: Yes, `print(type(str(range(mean))))` returns `str`. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: removing the `str()`function would remove your last mentioned issue. However, your next issue will be that you subtract a range from 0 to mean from the i,j value of your matrix. It is not clear what you try to achieve with your code. I would suggest break down the process in your function into separate functions (e.g., def calculate_mean_for_column(), calculate_sd(), ...). Tests these functions separately and then call them in another function in a way that achieves what you want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237002/discussion-between-marcel-h-and-meloqq).